# Importing fields from ExpressionEngine 2 to Craft

Tags: craft3, import

sorry if this is posted somewhere. I couldn't find it.

I'm trying to export a site from EE2 to Craft 3. All the tutorials I've found only export/import the pages and it seems like you have to create all the fields/field groups manually. My site has over 250 fields so this is obviously not ideal. Is there an export/import that works for fields as well? TIA

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to import fields, but really this is not something you should be aiming to do, especially from EE where field groups basically had a 1:1 relationship with channels. In Craft you won't need anywhere near as many fields as you used in EE because they'll be shared across different sections. Take this golden opportunity to clean up the technical debt instead of recreating it in Craft.

Comment: @JamesSmith Field groups yes, but fields? I'm very new to both but it was my understanding that fields were reusable across field groups in EE as well? So not that much technical debt